# Automapper With NHibernate and DevExpress GridView - Caching

Tags: c#, nhibernate, webforms, devexpress, automapper

My WebForms project uses an NHibernate class library as an OR mapper to our Oracle databases.  The NHibernate library has been fully tested and is working without any issues.

Global.asax.cs:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    var cnnConfig = ""; //contains connection string information for NH
    NHibernateClassLibrary.init(cnnConfig); //initializes NHibernate


        var profileType = typeof(AutoMapper.Profile);
        // Get an instance of each Profile in the executing assembly.
        var profiles = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
            .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
            .Cast<Profile>();

        // Initialize AutoMapper with each instance of the profiles found.
        Mapper.Initialize(a => profiles.ForEach(a.AddProfile)); //ForEach is an extension method
}
```

ExtensionMethods.cs:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
            Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T item in enumerable) { action(item); }
    }
}
```

SampleProfile.cs:

```
namespace MyProjectName.AutomapperProfiles
{
    public class EntityOneProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            base.Configure();
            Mapper.CreateMap<NHibernateClassLibrary.Entities.EntityOne, EntityOnePoco>();
        }
    }
}
```

EntityOne.cs:

```
namespace NHibernateClassLibrary.Entities
{
    public class EntityOne
    {
        public virtual string PropertyOne { get; set; }
        public virtual string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
        public virtual string PropertyThree { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EntityOnePoco.cs:

```
namespace MyProjectName.GridEntities
{
    public class EntityOnePoco
    {
        public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
        public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
        public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MyPage.aspx.cs:

```
namespace MyProjectName
{
    public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //This gets us access to the NHibernate Class Library
        IDATABASE DataBase = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDATABASE>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var EntityOneRaw = DataBase.EntityOne.ToList();
            var EntityOneObjects = EntityOneRaw.Select(q => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<NHibernateClassLibrary.Entities.EntityOne, EntityOnePoco>(q)).ToList();
            GridViewObject.DataSource = new BindingList<EntityOnePoco>(EntityOneObjects);
            GridViewObject.DataBind();

        }

        protected void ButtonOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Item = DataBase.EntityOne.First();
            Item.PropertyTwo = "New Value";
            DataBase.SaveChanges(); //NHibernate call to commit
        }
    }
}
```

MyPage.aspx:

```
<!--Other lines truncated-->
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="GridViewObject" runat="server" KeyFieldName="PropertyOne">
</dx:ASPxGridView>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonOne" runat="server" Text="Take Action" OnClick="ButtonOne_Click" />
```

The page_load method works fine.  The grid will load with the database's current values, with the first entry's "PropertyTwo" equal to "Old Value" for example.  If I press ButtonOne, the ButtonOne_Click method will fire and update the first entry in the EntityOne table appropriately.  I've confirmed this directly in Oracle.  Further, a breakpoint set right after this action completes shows that the NHibernateClassLibrary is appropriately fetching the new property.  However, the GridView is still displaying "Old Value" until I stop IIS/Debugging and restart.

My first instinct is that caching is enabled somewhere, but I've confirmed NHibernate is not caching the old value.  If EntityOne from the database is up to date, how do I force the AutoMapped EntityOnePoco to update at the same time?  Am I missing something easy here?

Comment: Could it be the browser cache?

Comment: Try to disable ASPxGridView.EnableRowsCache (https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_EnableRowsCachetopic)

Comment: APSxGridView.EnableRowsCache is not the issue.  I've narrowed down that the raw data coming from NHibernate contains the correct, up-to-date value, but AutoMapper is somehow caching the previous value.  Calling Automapper.Mapper.Reset() will throw the exception "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to call DataBase.Clear(), essentially clearing the first-level NHibernate cache right before populating the EntityOneRaw object, as in the following example.  My use-case benefits from first-level caching, so in my actual code, I only call the Clear() method as necessary.

```
namespace MyProjectName
{
    public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //This gets us access to the NHibernate Class Library
        IDATABASE DataBase = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDATABASE>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataBase.Clear(); //clear the first-level cache in NHibernaet
            var EntityOneRaw = DataBase.EntityOne.ToList();
            var EntityOneObjects = EntityOneRaw.Select(q => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<NHibernateClassLibrary.Entities.EntityOne, EntityOnePoco>(q)).ToList();
            GridViewObject.DataSource = new BindingList<EntityOnePoco>(EntityOneObjects);
            GridViewObject.DataBind();

        }

        protected void ButtonOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Item = DataBase.EntityOne.First();
            Item.PropertyTwo = "New Value";
            DataBase.SaveChanges(); //NHibernate call to commit
        }
    }
}
```